# Getting a track ID on Spotify for using it in the Spotify API

Tags: c#, api, spotify

I'm trying to use the Spotify API and I need the id of a specific track but I don't find any solution regarding how to obtain that ID.
Any ideas?

Read a lot of documentation. The information was useful, but I didn't find anything regarding to my topic

Comment: the id is returned in the json result for a search - in other words you can use the "search" endpoint and include the track name and artist in the query to get the id back

Answer (score 0):

Found a pretty simple method. For anyone interested, if you use the desktop app you can drag the name of the song in a text editor and it will give you the id

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).